# Event not firing as expected for control in formview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a LinkButton in an InsertItemTemplate which when clicked, should display a hidden DropDownList in the InsertItemTemplate. However, it doesn't seem to be working, but it will say, change the text of a label outside the Formview when the LinkButton is clicked. The event is firing, but the part to make the DropDownList visible in the InsertItemTemplate is not doing anything. Code is below:

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:FormView ID="formViewNewRecord" runat="server">
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddSelection2" runat="server" DataSourceID="dSource1" DataTextField="Users"  DataValueField="Users" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Visible="false">
                <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbAddAnother" OnClick="lbAddAnother_Click">+Add Another</asp:LinkButton>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**C#:**

```
protected void lbAddAnother_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList addSelection2 = (DropDownList)formViewNewItem.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlAddSelection2");
    addSelection2.Visible = true;
    Label2.Text = addSelection2.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown control is not an immediate child of your formview. So since the FindControl call is not recursive, you have to search for the control in the right location of your form view's child controls. [See this for the details](http://forums.asp.net/t/1428282.aspx) but at a high level, you need something along the lines of:

```
DropDownList ctrl = (DropDownList)FormView1.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlAddSelection2");
```

After that, you should check it for null for safe measure.

Comment: Hi @Tombala I updated my code above. I added the .Row.Cells[0], and it still isn't working. I also added the Label to display the ID of the control. The label does display 'ddlAddSelection2' when clicking the LinkButton. It happens regardless of whether I keep or omit the .Row.Cell[0] piece, but still the control I'm trying to make visible is not happening.

Comment: What I would do is what was also suggested at the discussion on the link: break on that line and use the watch window or immediate window to figure out where the control you need is located in the controls tree. Then you can use that correct path to your control.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you seem to be suggesting that the FindControl is just not finding the control because of the path (control name) that is being used in the FindControl(). To me that does not make sense, because it is displaying the control's ID it finds in a Label I placed outside the formview. If I put an incorrect control name such as `.FindControl('ddlAddSelection23')` it will give me a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error. I'm thinking this problem I'm having is related to the Page life cycle??

Comment: Just an update on this...so I decided to create a brand new project with just a formview, linkbutton, and the code-behind code I've been using and it works fine. So it's some setting or code outside of this that appears to be causing this to not work... :/

Comment: To address your first comment about the control path, no, the control ID stays the same. I meant that unless you execute the "FindControl" method on the immediate parent container of your control, you will not find it. The Label is found because your label is in the controls collection of your page. But the dropdown list is not an immediate child of your FormView. It's the child of one of the templates. I would still put a breakpoint on that line and look through the properties of your formview and drill down into the controls collection, rows, etc, until you find the ctrl you're looking for.